# Pushing certain chars to certain strings. Infix to postfix

Tags: java, calculator, infix-notation

I want to make a calculator that converts infix to postfix, using only strings and characters.

here's the requirements:

> for i=1 to m:
>   if c_i is an operand: Transfer c_i to output.
>   -if c_i is a left parentheses: Push c_i to tmp.
>   -if c_i is a right parentheses: Pop elements from tmp and transfer
>   -them to output until a left-parentheses
>   -is met. Pop left-parentheses.
>   if c_i is an operator: Let the top tmp element be t. Pop and
>   -transfer elements from tmp to output
>   -until:
>   -p(t) < p(c_i) or
>   -t is a left-parentheses or
>   -tmp is empty.
>   -Push c_i to tmp.

```
static String infixToPostfix(String infix){
String postfix = "";
infix = readLine();
String temp ="";
String output ="";


for (int i=0 ; i<infix.length(); i++) {

    if (infix.charAt(i) == '+') {
           infix = postfix;
    }

    else  if (infix.charAt(i) == '-') {
                infix = postfix;
    }

    else  if (infix.charAt(i) == '*') {
                infix = postfix;
    }      
   else   if (infix.charAt(i) == '/') {
                infix = postfix;
   }    
   else   if (infix.charAt(i) == '(') {
            infix = temp ; 
   }

   else if (infix.charAt(i) == ')') {
         temp=postfix; 

        }

    }



    return postfix;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be incomplete. Here is my own method to convert an *Infix* `String` to *Postfix*. Hope it helps.

```
boolean chk = true;
for(int i=0; i<expression.length(); i++) {
    char ch = expression.charAt(i);

    //Conditions for generating postfix String
    if(ch=='(') {
        operator.push(ch);
        chk=false;
    }
    else if(isDigit(ch)) {
        if(!chk) {
            postfix = postfix + " " + ch;
        }
        else {
            postfix = postfix + ch;
        }
        chk=true;
    }
    else if(ch == '+' || ch=='-') {
        if(operator.isEmpty()) {
            operator.push(ch);
    }
    else if(operator.peep()=='/'|| perator.peep()=='*'||operator.peep()=='-') {
            postfix = postfix + " " + operator.pop();
            operator.push(ch);
        }
            else {
            operator.push(ch);
        }
        chk = false;
    }
    else if(ch == '*' || ch == '/') {

        if(operator.isEmpty()) {
            operator.push(ch);
        }
            else if(operator.peep()=='+' || operator.peep()=='-') {
            operator.push(ch);
        }
            else {
            postfix = postfix + " " + operator.pop();
            operator.push(ch);
        }
        chk = false;
    }
    else if(ch == ')') {
        while(operator.peep()!='(') {
            postfix = postfix + " " + operator.pop();
        }           
        operator.pop();
    }
}
    while(!operator.isEmpty()) {
        postfix = postfix + " " + operator.pop();
    }
```